# issue with a for loop in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a method to calculate the exponent, but it doesnt like the c := c * a. If i do something like c := a. it works and im unsure why its behaving this way when i try and do c := c *a.. Im new to Smalltalk, so maybe its just something im missing. Im using Pharo as my implementaton.

```
testPow: i1 exp: i2
    "Testing exponent. i1 and i2 are integers, we calculate and then return the value as a Church numeral"
    | a b c |

    a := i1.
    b := i2.

        1 to: b do: [ :i |
      c:= c*a.
    ].
^c.
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't "like"  `c := c * a` because c isn't initialized. You can't compute *c times a* without knowing the value of c.

Comment: Thanks it worked! Post it as an answer so i can accept it.

Comment: also note that you do not need extra local variables a and b, you could just use arguments i1 and i2

Comment: Please also note that giving variables names like `i1` or `c` is not very Smalltalk-like, nor is using abbreviations like "pow" and "exp". Spelling it out won't kill you, and Smalltalk is big on readability for good reason. Using something along the lines of `powerOf: aBase exponent: anExponent` would be more appropriate. ;-)

Comment: Just to add that when a method does not refer to 'self' or to an instance variable, this is a sign that there might be a design problem. In your case, you will have code like "self testPow: 10 exp: 20" and 'self' here is totally useless. The Smalltalk way of expressing the same thing would be "10 pow: 20" which would require you to implement your method #pow: in the class Number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialise `c` before using it. With your statement:

```
c := a
```

it works because `a` has a value. With:

```
c := c * a
```

it won't work because the first time through the loop, `c` will not be initialised to anything useful.

Just change your initialisation section to:

```
a := i1.
b := i2.
c := 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the sample c is pointing to nil because c was not initialized. And nil (which is an object) doesn't understand the message *. Look at the values in the debugger when the exception is thrown.